# How do you stop clipping of gameobjects with colliers?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm having an issue with clipping when too much force is applied to one GameObject against another. My Gameobjects have rigidbodies and colliers attached to them. What is the best way to stop this? My initial idea was to put ray casts on the sides of each object and when interacting with each other it could normalize or cap velocity. What would be the best way to go about this or if there is a better alternative what is it?

Comment: Are you sure you're actually moving them with a force, or are you arbitrarily setting/moving their position? It looks like your character movement is overriding the physics simulation in your game - how does it influence the box that it's dragging?

Comment: the boxes are being moved along the belt with rigidbody.Addforce(). When the character grabs the box the gameobject.transform is being set to the parents transform(Player). Is this the issue because transform works on world space and not the physics system?

Comment: Yes, that'd be the case if your player isn't also being moved with AddForce() and a Rigidbody. Once you parent the box underneath the player, you're essentially taking the box out of the physics simulation and risk having unexpected physical interactions with other objects.

Comment: is there a different way to achieve an object following the player like that without causing this issue that you know of?

Comment: I'd suggest looking into a [Fixed Joint](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-FixedJoint.html). These let you connect two objects without parenting, and will break if too much force is applied (so if the box is blocked, it'll stop instead of being teleported into the other boxes). If that doesn't completely work, you may also need to change how you move your player - using the physics simulation instead of directly moving its position.

Comment: Alright, thanks for the tips. I'll do some experimenting tonight and let you know how it goes.

Comment: Great - if you run into problems implementing a solution, then update your question to show your progress and the issues you're facing. That would probably attract more people to try to answer your question, since at the moment it's a little broad in scope.

Comment: Will do, still trying to get the hang of asking the right questions. Thats harder than programming  sometimes